# Paste Special without formulas but with link

Tags: hyperlink, paste

I try to past list of rows from one sheet to another, based on condition but without formulas and format, except for one column where there is a link to another document and link needs to be copied too. Any idea how to work around with ActiveSheet.Paste Special to ignore formula but having link pasted? Thx (see code below)

```
Sub Button3_Click()
a = Worksheets("Target List").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Target List").Cells(i, 17).Value = "Yes" Then
Worksheets("Target List").Rows(i).Copy
Worksheets("Completed List").Activate

b = Worksheets("Completed List").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Completed List").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=True

Worksheets("Target List").Activate

End If


Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Target List").Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("Q8:R" & Range("Q8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you searching an answer. I came with own solution by pasting the values first and then unique link separately and it works. See below, you can adjust for your own purpose

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim HL As Hyperlink
a = Worksheets("Target List").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Target List").Cells(i, 17).Value = "Yes" Then
Worksheets("Target List").Rows(i).Copy
Worksheets("Completed List").Activate

b = Worksheets("Completed List").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Completed List").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=True

Worksheets("Target List").Activate
Worksheets("Target List").Cells(i, 19).Copy
Worksheets("Completed List").Activate
Worksheets("Completed List").Cells(b + 1, 19).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Link:=True


Worksheets("Target List").Activate

End If


Next


Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Target List").Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("Q8:U" & Range("Q8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents


End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).